# Access Apache virtual host over lan

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost, lan

i configured my xampp to use vhost

on apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf i have

```
NameVirtualHost *:80  //uncommented

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "Z:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost web1.project>
DocumentRoot "Z:/xampp/htdocs/web1" 
ServerName web1.project

<Directory "Z:/xampp/htdocs/web1">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

then on windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts i have

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 web1.project
```

on my machine its works perfect, i can go direct on browser and access http://web1.project

but on another machines on same lan, dont works, ok i figured my IP

my network map i have all ips for each machine on my lan

the computer here xampp is running have 192.168.1.221

so like on my tablet i can go 192.168.1.221 and i have xampp running

if i go 192.168.1.221/web1  works

but http://web1.project don't works

any idea, what i need to do to have put this to work?

thanks.

Comment: your tablet won't know where web1.project name resolves to, unless you can add it to it's dns, or your router's dns.

Comment: Hi @flauntster, can you give me a help on this, how i can setup on my router https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gixu2ztbsmcein/Snap%202014-03-25%20at%2023.08.32.png what i need to do, based on information on my question. THanks.

Answer (score 3):

web1.project is not registered in your DNS.

A quick and dirty way to test it on other computer , you can add `<IP ADDRESS> web1.project` in its `/etc/hosts`. 
On android device, you can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treb.hosts to modify that `/etc/hosts` file in android device(though I have never tested it though)

Comment: how about using a smartphone. How do I access the virtual host I have configured?