# How to access XAMPP virtual host from another computer or device?

Tags: php, xampp, virtualhost

I want to access my virtual host using my phone or my other computer the problem is I cannot access my site using the server name I can only access the site using the IP address of the server. I changed the port to **7777**

When I tried ***www.tbs.com:7777/index.php*** I am getting "**site cannot be reached**"

**Virtual Host Config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:7777>
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/TBSApp"
ServerName www.tbs.com
ServerAlias tbs.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/TBSApp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Host Config**

```
192.168.120.9    www.tbs.com
```

Comment: you probably need to look at the DNS on network and network naming ( depending if Linux, Mac, Win ) anyhow it is also probably a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650186/access-apache-virtual-host-over-lan)

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I need to configure the DNS?

Comment: what computer do you use to access ? did you changed hosts file on windows ? and did you restart apache to take all changes ? firewall config?

Comment: also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network) probably covers most.

Comment: i am using my laptop and my phone. I changed the host file. What do I do in my firewall? I added inbound and outbound rules for port 7777 what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ip address instead of the domain as it is a local host configuration. To use the domain across all devices you need to setup a DNS server.

Comment: how about accessing the site using the computer name instead of an ip address is it possible?

Comment: I don't think you can. I am fairly sure that is just used in ssh. If you are using windows just do ipconfig in command prompt or in mac/linux do ifconfig in terminal to get your ip address.